# "Request failed with http status code 503" while using CloudKit

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, cloudkit

While I try to fetch some records from database:

```
let query = CKQuery(recordType: "Service", predicate: NSPredicate(value: true))
database.perform(query, inZoneWith: nil) { records, error in

    print(error?.localizedDescription)
    if let records = records, error == nil {
        parseAndSaveServices(with: records)
    }
}
```

The error is following:

```
Optional("Request failed with http status code 503")
```

or:

```
Optional("Internal server error")
```

And when I try to connect to my Cloud Kit Dashboard then:

[image]

What does it mean? What should I do then?

Comment: Are you still having this problem? At the time you posted the question, iCloud was experiencing a major outage, but it seems to be working now.

Comment: no it is working now

Comment: Rule 1 of using online APIs: Make sure the service is running before you assume your code is broken. :)